# How can a literal control in asp.net be populated?

Tags: asp.net, controls, literals

I'm new with using literal controls in ASP.NET and it is confusing me a lot. I read about it but I still have no idea how are they being populated in the ASP.NET app code I have right now. When I open the application, the website opens with two texts in the control, but I cannot find out from where is the text coming. I have done a search too in the whole project, trying to find the words from the text in the project, but I always get 0 results.

When I delete the connection strings, the text (literal control) still renders, it means the text doesn't come from the database.

How can the literal control be populated with text when I cannot find the text anywhere?

```
    <!-- Page -->
<asp:Literal ID="PageInformationIntro" runat="server" />
<ul class="list">
    <li><a href="/start">Start</a></li>
</ul>
<asp:Literal ID="PageInformationHelp" runat="server" />
<ul class="list">
    <li><a href="/go">GO</a></li>
</ul>
<asp:Literal ID="PageInformationSystem" runat="server" />
```

And the text appears where the literal controls are. I did some debugging too but I couldn't find anything :(

Comment: do you have any .aspx files in your project? or are you using MVC?

Comment: only .aspx files, I´m not using MVC

Comment: at least post some of your markup and where you're trying to change the text